# White noise through mic even when muted

Tags: microphone, audacity, usb

I am trying to record audio but even when the mic is muted the recording picks up white noise. It's not the mic because I've tried it with my headset mic and the same issue occurs. Not software either because it happens in both Audacity and OBS. I have an MSI B550-A Pro and I have the Realtek drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, computer sound cards are just not of sufficient quality for professional quality audio recording.

Matched to a high impedance mic on a headset for use on Zoom etc they're about OK, but if you have a low impedance mic, then the levels won't match properly & the noise floor will become more apparent.

I'd suggest a USB audio interface. Get one with phantom power in case you need it for a condenser mic either now or later on.

Google "USB audio interface" for a myriad suggestions, starting at around $£€ 30. Look at the big online music shops who will have a good selection & offer advice as to precisely what will suit your needs.

If you edit in your mic type/model/pictures etc then we could perhaps be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

First a word of warning: mainboard sound equipment tends to be of limited quality, and the inputs, particularly the microphone level inputs, tend to be considerably worse than the outputs in that regard.

That being said, the MSI B550-A Pro mainboard appears to feature a Realtek ALC892 Codec for its audio, and the specifications for that include the following blurb:

> Port-B/C/E/F with software selectable boost gain (+10/+20/+30dB) for analog microphone input

The inputs you are talking about will use 3.5mm plugs and electret condenser microphone capsules powered by the input (this includes your headset microphone).  Better bulk capsules of that kind offer about 60dB dynamic range while a good large diaphragm studio condenser microphone (generally, anything with "professional" or "studio" in its name is neither) will get you in the 100dB ballpark.  Which means a difference in noise power by a factor of 10000.

So given the microphones you are likely working with, you cannot expect wonders in audio quality regarding the noise floor independently of what you connect them with.  However, you say that even the muted microphones are too noisy for your taste.

That makes it likely that you are not yet getting the best from your modest equipment.  I would definitely check that you find software that allows you to set the various microphone boost levels (which should be implemented in analog and thus actually have a chance to make a difference) and make sure that you have set them to the highest setting that will not yet cause distortion.  If you record with that level and afterwards adjust the volume for comfortable hearing, you should get the minimum of noise that you can hope to get with your equipment.

That's basically what is called "gain staging", making sure that one makes best use of the amplification and amplitude limits of various stages (analog and digital) in processing.

With regard to costs for better equipment, the sky is the limit, so it makes sense exploring just how far you can get with the given equipment towards your goals before starting to plan the next iteration, if any.